# Regex for.. URL in a URL?

Tags: rewrite, .htaccess, url

I have the following line in my .htaccess file, but it keeps redirecting me to a 404 error.

RewriteRule ^path1/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(.+)(/?)$ /file.php?variable1=$1&variable2=$2 [nc]

An example link would be..

http://domain.com/path1/name23/http://domain2.com/stuff/is/here

I want to turn transfer that 2nd URL to variable2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RewriteRule ^path1/([a-z0-9_-]+)/([^\?]+)$ /file.php?variable1=$1&variable2=$2 [NC]

Try the above rule and see. Your pattern is not matching that why you get the 404 error.
By the way, I remove A-Z because NC will make it case-insensitive anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think that with only [NC] apache is looking for a file called 'file.php?variable1=$1&variable2=$2' (with variable subsitued) on the hard drive.
You can try with [R,NC] or [PT,NC] (this one need mod_proxy)

Answer (score 0):

Increase log level to Debug and see that mod_rewrite is doing.